# English to Telugu Dictionary for ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dictionary, open-source

is there any English to Telugu Opensource dictionary tool for Ubuntu 14.04? or for any other Linux distributions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

From the T list of aspell:

```
T
Tagalog dictionary aspell-tl
Tamil dictionary aspell-ta
Telugu dictionary aspell-te
Tsonga dictionary aspel-ts
Tswana dictionary aspel-tn
```

So in USC:

[image]

Comment: but it is only for spell check not for any translation